# My Settings.plist is not being read properly

Tags: ios, plist, settings.bundle

So I have setup a settings.plist and can read the data properly. now I have 2 `PSTextFieldSpecifier`in the settings, so I gave given them each a different `Key`

Now when I run the app, the one field works and the other one does not - the code for retrieving the information for both is identical, this is even confirmed when I swap the key identifiers, however as soon as I change one of the names to anything at all, it stops working. - of course everything is updated in the code to reflect this.

I have pasted the code of the plist so you can see it is identical. What could be wrong??

```
        <dict>
        <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
        <string>None</string>
        <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
        <string>No</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>IsSecure</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>customer_ID_preference</string>
        <key>KeyboardType</key>
        <string>Alphabet</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Customer ID</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
        <string>None</string>
        <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
        <string>No</string>
        <key>IsSecure</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>password_preference</string>
        <key>KeyboardType</key>
        <string>Alphabet</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Password</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
```

Cheers

---EDIT---

So I have figured out so far that for some reason the textFields only accepts numbers - however when I put in letters in straight away it works fine - so is that a settigns bundle feature/limitation I should change?